# Keyboard shortcut for cascading multiple windows of same application in macOs

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

Need to know,

Is there any app, which gives a keyboard shortcut Or any inbuilt keyboard shortcut
to cascade windows(attached pic for reference) of same in application in macOs

Note that I'm not asking about Expose shortcut

[image: cascaded windows of same application]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently if you hold the ["Option" key wile selecting "Arrange In Front"](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27166117#message27166117) from the Window menu of your application, that should do what you want. To make a shortcut for that, you should be able to add a shortcut in the keyboard preferences.

You might also look into [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/)

Comment: I wish there was a similar feature that worked for all windows across apps.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Application windows` shortcut for this. It's the same as `App Axpose` gesture on a trackpad that expose not all windows but only windows of current application.

After windows is exposed, you can choose particular window by `← ↑ ↓ →` keys.

[image: mac os show Application windows shortcut]

Comment: the 2nd part was helpful.  it wasn't working for me because I was holding the cmd key down.